# C++ how to align each line for a file?

Tags: c++, openmp

I want to use openMP to read a big file which contains lots of lines from disk. One way to do it seems to use `seekg()` function. But the headache part is `seekg()` only support to move the file index to a particular byte.

This works fine if the size of each line is exactly the same. But I have no idea that how to do it if the size of each line is totally different. 
So could you give me some hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility:

- Divide the file into equal-sized chunks based on bytes, one for each parallel task, without regard to line endings.
- Have each task seek to the beginning of its chunk, then read *and ignore* characters until it finds a line ending, so that it can start processing the file at the beginning of a line.  (As a special case, the task that starts at offset 0 should not do this, because it's already at the beginning of a line.)
- When a task reaches the end of its chunk (i.e. the byte offset where the next chunk begins), *continue reading past that point* to the end of the current line.  (As a special case, the end of the last chunk is also the end of the file, so there's nothing to read past that point.)

Basically, you initially choose boundaries based on byte offsets, but then move them forward to coincide with line endings.  Each task skips some characters at the beginning of its chunk, and those characters are instead handled by another task reading past the end of the preceding chunk.

(I believe this is how Hadoop splits text-based input files by default, BTW.)

Comment: Thank you ~ I modified the code to save the bytes instead of strings to disk. And that works!

Comment: Files always hold bytes, so it's not clear what you mean about saving bytes instead of strings.  But to avoid one possible misinterpretation: when I said to divide the file into chunks, that doesn't mean you have to physically split it into smaller files.  You can keep all the text in a single file, but just choose evenly-spaced positions within it that the tasks will seek to.

Comment: One other thing to check for: if a task reaches the end of its chunk without finding even a single line ending, it should stop without processing any text at all.  That means you have a long line that spans three or more chunks, and the task(s) looking at the chunk(s) in the middle can't see the beginning of either that line or the next one, so they have nothing to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder :) I basically follow what you give me, and success!